# Techniques to get a meticulous polygon in R

Tags: r, plot

**Background:**

I have a `polygon()` that doesn't look as professional as I need it to be (**see my R code blow**).

I usually use two general techniques to make `ploygon()`s come out the way I want them to be. **First**, **in my curve**, I use **`lwd = larger than 1`**. **Second**, **in my polygon**, I remove the border of my `polygon()` by **`border = NA`**.

In this case below, for some reasons, I can NOT use the first technique.

**Question:**

I was wondering what else I can do **in addition to** removing the **`border=NA`** in my **`polygon()`** to improve my polygon?

```
curve(dnorm(x), -3, 3, bty="n", ann=F, axes=F, col="blue")

xs <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, len=1000)
polygon(c(xs[1], xs, xs[1000]), c(0, dnorm(xs), 0), col='grey', border = NA)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how much better this is, but maybe add `curve` after the `polygon`

```
curve(dnorm(x), -3, 3, bty="n", ann=F, axes=F, col=NA)
xs <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, len=1000)
polygon(c(xs[1], xs, xs[1000]), c(0, dnorm(xs), 0), col='grey', border = NA)
curve(dnorm(x), -3, 3, col='blue', add = TRUE, n = 1e4)
#n = 1e4 helps plot curve with more points (default in 101), making it smoother
```

Comment: `add` is not allowed with `plot`. You can begin with `plot`, but in subsequent steps use `polygon` and `curve`(with `add = TRUE` for curve)